# Origine dell'espressione "gli manca un venerdì"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Durante un quiz in TV è stata formulata una domanda di cosa mancava ad una persona strana, stravagante secondo un detto popolare.

La risposta era: gli manca un venerdì.

Ho cercato in giro possibili spiegazioni e ho trovato le seguenti:

> Il modo di dire allude, con molta probabilità, alla presunta
>   stravaganza di chi nasce prematuramente. Costoro sono ritenuti
>   "incompleti" e mancanti di qualche venerdí. E perché proprio venerdí?
>   Perché al venerdì sono collegati tradizionalmente manovre
>   scaramantiche, riti magici e pratiche occulte. ([Rubrica Scioglilingua
>   del Corriere](http://forum.corriere.it/scioglilingua/16-12-2009/gli-manca-un-venerdi-1432094.html))

> Questa espressione si riferisce probabilmente alle nascite premature
>   ed all’antica credenza popolare, ovviamente infondata, che i nati
>   prematuri (i “settimini” ad esempio) fossero incompleti e pertanto
>   mancanti anche di un po’ di cervello.
>
> Il riferimento al venerdì è legato alla tradizione Cristiana di giorno
>   del malaugurio (in quanto quello della Crocifissione) e quindi
>   all’importanza di averli trascorsi tutti (e quindi esorcizzati) nel
>   ventre materno. (*http://www.ilcondominionews.it/?p=1954*)

Qualcuno ha fonti più attendibili riguardo all'origine di questo detto? Perché proprio il venerdì e non un qualsiasi altro giorno della settimana?

Comment: As a side note, direi che è un’espressione un po’ antiquata, mi chiedo se i millennials la capirebbero.

Comment: L'ipotesi relativa a una nascita prematura è esposta anche nel _Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana_ di Carlo Lapucci: “Il detto allude forse alla presunta stranezza di chi nasce prematuramente, come si vuole che siano tali anche coloro che vengono alla luce più tardi (v.: Essere un _decimo_)” [cioè essere nato nel decimo mese di gravidanza].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Potrebbe essere una stupidaggine (specialmente perché non ne trovo conferma immediata su Google), ma avevo sentito qualcuno attribuire quest'espressione a un riferimento al romanzo [*Robinson Crusoe*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_Crusoe), del 1719.

In questo libro il protagonista fa naufragio su un'isola deserta del Pacifico dove vive per diversi anni, e deve combattere per sopravvivere alle avversità della natura e non ammattire nella completa solitudine. A un certo punto a lui si unisce un indigeno che lui ribattezza con il nome di 'Venerdì'.

L'idea quindi sarebbe che "gli manca solo di avere un Venerdì con lui per essere come Robinson Crusoe". Probabilmente apocrifa, me ne rendo conto. Non ho una fonte precisa, è solo un "sentito dire".

Comment: A quanto pare, [*Robinson Crusoe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_(Robinson_Crusoe)) è la fonte di un'espressione idiomatica in inglese ("man friday" e anche "girl friday"), quindi l'ipotesi mi sembra plausibile.